# Calling function from other file produces runtime error

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK for the first time and read up on how to call functions from other files, but I seem to be having issues. Here are the two scripts so far:

timer.lua

```
local M = {}
function M.Timer(n, count) --(period, how many times repeated)
    if count > 0 then
        local iter= os.time()+n
        while iter ~= os.time() do
        end
        M.onTime(count)
        count = count - 1
        M.Timer(n,count)
    end
end
function M.onTime(count)
    display.newtext(count,250,50,native.systemFont,16)  
end
return M
```

main.lua

```
local timeTool = require("timer")
timeTool.Timer(1,5)
```

They are located in the same directory. When I run main.lua on the simulator, I get the error `attempt to call field 'Timer' (a nil value)`. This leads me to believe that the main file failed in acquiring the contents of the timer script, but from what I've seen, I am using the correct syntax. Is there something I missed, or am I using the wrong method for calling functions from other scripts?

Comment: A side note: `iter ~= os.time()` may be ALWAYS true.  `iter > os.time()` is preferable.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind

Comment: May be try change name of file from `timer.lua` to `mytimer.lua`. The [`timer`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/index.html) library exists already.

Comment: Do you have check require success? or you can try to set the table M not local